# Python Dict truncates a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am playing around with Riemann integrals in python. 
I have a couple functions:

```
def myfunc(x, mu, sigma):

    px = np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return px

def get_area(h,mu,sigma):
    x = np.arange(-100,100+h,h)
    return sum([myfunc(xi,mu,sigma)*h for xi in x])
```

I am trying to explore the impact of variations in mu and sigma, on the area under the function. 
I do so in the following way:

```
sigma_range = [0.25,0.5,1,2]
h_range = [2,1,0.1,0.001,0.00001]

result_dict = {}

for sigma in sigma_range:
    sigma_dict = {}
    for h in h_range:
        sigma_dict[str(repr(h))] = sigma_dict.get(str(h), [])
        sigma_dict[str(repr(h))].append(get_area(h,1,sigma))
        result_dict[str(sigma)] = sigma_dict
```

Upon investigation, one of the sigma values (as a key) is truncated.
"0.00001" turns into "1e-05".

```
result_dict["0.25"]

{'2': [0.0013418505116100474],
 '1': [1.0006709252558303],
 '0.1': [0.6266570686577856],
 '0.001': [0.6266570686547552],
 '1e-05': [0.6266570684587373]}
```

Which results in another error, when I place it in a pandas DataFrame, the sequence of the keys gets mixed up too

[image]

If they were at least in the correct order, I could live with it, as analysis would be simple.
However, having to jump from one row to another, makes the process tedious.

Prior to posting, I read around and saw that sometimes getting the repr() of a value works, however that didn't work.

I thought that maybe increasing the column width would help, but that only works for value columns rather than the index (irregardless, the problem occurs when creating the dictionary rather than the DF itself.

Comment: Why do you use your key as a string and not simply as a float?

Comment: I don't understand which key is getting truncated, do you mind being more specific? Also, what is the desired result?

Comment: @torresmateo, "0.00001" turns into "1e-05" (maybe 'truncated' is not the right word to use in this context). 

I want my final result, for now, to be a DF which compares areas, depending on h (index) and sigma (colums).

Comment: @LeoE I tried with keys being floats, but I get the same result, "0.00001" turns into "1e-05"

Comment: It does not for me, the Dataframe is sorted properly. No changes from `0.00001` to `1e-05` during Dataframe creation

Comment: 0.00001 and 1e-05 *are the same number*, not fundamentally different than 1 and 01 being the same number.

Comment: @jasonharper I am aware that they are in fact the same number, represented in different ways. However that does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should try with the options you can pass to `format`.

In particular, the float specification: `"{:f}"`

```
for sigma in sigma_range:
    sigma_dict = {}
    for h in h_range:
        sigma_dict["{:f}".format(h)] = sigma_dict.get(str(h), [])
        sigma_dict["{:f}".format(h)].append(get_area(h,1,sigma))
        result_dict[str(sigma)] = sigma_dict
```

Then:

```
>>> result_dict["0.25"]
{'2.000000': [0.0013418505116100474],
 '1.000000': [1.0006709252558303],
 '0.100000': [0.6266570686577856],
 '0.001000': [0.6266570686547552],
 '0.000010': [0.6266570684587373]}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any formats etc. Just use floats as Keys instead of strings, as suggested in the comments.
This code:

```
result_dict = {}

for sigma in sigma_range:
    sigma_dict = {}
    for h in h_range:
        sigma_dict[h] = sigma_dict.get(h, [])
        sigma_dict[h].append(get_area(h,1,sigma))
        result_dict[sigma] = sigma_dict
df = pd.DataFrame(result_dict)
```

Produces this dataframe:

```
                            0.25
0.00001      [0.626657068681351]
0.00100     [0.6266570686580978]
0.10000     [0.6266570686577523]
1.00000     [1.0006709252558303]
2.00000  [0.0013418505116100474]
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already tried doing so, however I ended up with the same result. 
The answer below (formatting suggestion) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The float specification: `"{:f}"` works unless you don't need 7 decimal places

`"{:f}".format(0.00000001)` will give you `"0.000000"`

Comment: It works as a temporary solution.
However I should be wary when using it in the future. 
Thank you!